# The different behavior of OR operator in regex when captured or not

Tags: regex

I have two Regex expression, one is `^0|[1-9][0-9]*$`, another one is `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)`, the first expression matches string `"01"`, while the later one can't. What's the difference of the two expressions? In my opinion, the later only captures the matched string. I want to know why the later can't match `"01"` string.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `$` in the 2nd regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See graphic explanation

```
^0|[1-9][0-9]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m_ux_kwANkHYQPP0)

**Versus**

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4toHzjFwjYF8axSS)

So second RegEx requires string to be either "0" or to start with 1-9 character.

Answer (score 1):

Look at them this way:

```
^0            # Match a 0 at the start of the string
|             # or
[1-9][0-9]*$  # match a number > 1 at the end of the string.
```

versus

```
^             # Match the start of the string.
(             # Start of group 1:
 0            # Match a zero
|             # or
 [1-9][0-9]*  # a number > 1.
)             # End of group 1.
$             # Match the end of the string.
```

The alternation extends to the anchors in the first example whereas it's contained within the group in the second example.